# Keys repeating when running VMware virtual machine over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine, crash, vmware-player

I have SSH'd into another machine with a command of the form `$ ssh -X user@network`, typed the correct password and then ran VMware's VMPlayer from terminal with the command `$ vmplayer &`.  However, when I run the RedHat Virtual Machine from there, when I enter a username to login, the last letter I press repeats, i.e. when attempting to enter "root", I get "rootttttttttttt...".  An update window appears however when I try to install the update, this crashes my host system which I used to SSH (Linux).  What might be causing this, and how could I mitigate this issue?  I get the key repeating problem when doing this from two different machines which are running the same OS.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with Windows clients and connecting to the console.  The VMPros Blog posted a [fix to the parameters](https://blog.vmpros.nl/2015/04/07/vmware-repeated-characters-when-typing-in-remote-console/) of the virtual machine that increases latency in the keyboard driver before it will consider a key press to be held long enough for auto-repeat.

I know that this only works for console keyboard drivers, but it illustrates an idea that a parameter can be tuned to reduce this problem.  Get a list of all parameters and their current setting with PowerCLI and the command `Get-VM MyVM | Get-VMAdvancedConfiguration`.